# Call functions of a class instance from other file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a bot.js class in which I made the function getUserInventory. I required bot.js in my main file app.js and created a new instance.

**bot.js**

```
class SteamBot {

    constructor(logOnOptions){

        [...]
        this.logOn(logOnOptions);

    }

    logOn(logOnOptions){

        [...]

    }

    getUserInventory(sid, gameid, contextid, onlyTradeable, callback){
        [...]
    }

}

module.exports = SteamBot;
```

**app.js**

```
const SteamBot = require('./bots/bot.js');

const bot = new SteamBot({
    'logOnOptions'
});
```

Now I can call the function getUserInventory in my app.js file by just typing `bot.getUserInventory(...)`.

But what if I want to call the function in another file? Do I have to just type the same code that I wrote in app.js? Or would that cause problems?

I am a beginner.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking (or, more accurately, why). You can always create a new instance of a "class" and call its methods.

Comment: No, it doesn't just work in other modules. You would need to somehow get access to that `bot` variable/value first - either by exporting and importing it, or by passing it explicitly to an imported function as an argument. There's no difference between `bot` and `SteamBot` in that regard.

Answer (score 4):

When you are calling `new SteamBot();` you are creating a new instance of a `SteamBot`, it depends how you intend to use your SteamBot, do you need multiple steambots or just one ? If you only need one instance in your app,I would advise you to do something like that :

file /steambot.class.js

```
// this file contains your class
class SteamBot {

    ...
}

module.exports = SteamBot;
```

file /steambot.js

```
const SteamBotClass = require('./steambot.class');
let SteamBot;

module.exports = function(...args) {
    SteamBot = SteamBot || new SteamBotClass(...args);
    return SteamBot;
};
```

/app.js

```
const SteamBot = require('./steambot')({
    'logOnOptions'
});
```

And if you want to use in a third file the same instance:

```
const SteamBot = require('./steambot')();
```

with this structure, in your app, you would be able to create a new class if you need it one day, with just the `.class.js` file, but if you need to keep one instance of `SteamBot` all along the app, just require `steambot.js`.

it gives you a singleton pattern based on file, a bit different from the answer from Grégory which I also like.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you perhaps turn you answer into a `MWE`? My interpretation of your solution trows error: Unexpected token (8:0)` at the `app.js` (after removing the `...args` and replacing the constructor with `constructor(){};`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in `app.js` is instantiate a new `object` of the `class` `SteamBot`.

Then you are calling the method `getUserInventory` of that object.

---

> Can you call the method of this object from another file?

Yes if you pass to that file the object you just created. If not you gotta instantiate a new object, which can be a mistake due to the fact that i'll be totally different from the first object you did created (an other implementation of the class that's going to have it's own attributes).

---

To pass through the object instantiation you have two things you can do :

- Use static methods. A static method do not require an instantiation.

example:

`SteamBot.getUserInventory(...)`

```
class SteamBot {

   static getUserInventory(...)  {
     ...
   }

}
```

- Use singleton pattern, that will allow the creation of only one instance of a class.

example:

```
let instance = null;

class SteamBot {

 constructor() {
   if (instance) return instance;

   instance = this;

   return instance;
 }

 static getInstance() {
   return instance || new SteamBot();
 }

}
```

Comment: I like that also :)

Comment: In node.js you don't need to implement singleton pattern, each module is loaded only once. All what you need is to export created object: `module.exports = new Steambot();`

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't mater how you name your bot variable. If you name it `bot` you will call `bot.getUserInventory(...)`, if `anotherBot` then `anotherBot.getUserInventory(...)` if `foo` then `foo.getUserInventory(...)` and so on